# vb.NET "{0}" concatenation doesn't work in MySQL commands but "&" does

Tags: mysql, vb.net, concatenation

I've been trying to send a long MySQL command in vb.NET. When I want to use variables as part of the MySQL command string I've been concatenating the string using "&".

This works, but makes my code look messy, so I tried using "{0}, {1}" etc.

This however does not work and I get the error:

> Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'New' accepts this number of arguments.

Examples:

```
connector.Open()
commander = New MySqlCommand("UPDATE 'pupil_data' SET '" & Question & "'='" & Answer & "' WHERE 'username'=" & Environment.UserName & ";", connector)
dataAdapter = New MySqlDataAdapter(commander)
connector.Close()
```

This works, however:

```
connector.Open()
commander = New MySqlCommand(("UPDATE 'pupil_data' SET '{0}'='{1}' WHERE 'username'='{2}'", Question, Answer, Environment.Username), connector)
dataAdapter = New MySqlDataAdapter(commander)
connector.Close()
```

Doesn't work. It could just be a problem with my bracketing but I've tried several combinations and it's logically sound (I think).

Comment: string do not automatically use the format mask.  you should use `String.Format("UPDATE pupil_data...", arg1, arg2...)` with the mask and args to get the result. and place that inside New SQLCommand or create the string to a temp var and pass it

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean by mask. Can you clarify?

Comment: This is not a 90's party. Today *(and yesterday)* we use prepared/parameterized statements: [How do I create a parameterized SQL query? Why Should I?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/542510/how-do-i-create-a-parameterized-sql-query-why-should-i/542542#comment44610013_542542).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "{n}" designations do not represent automatic concatenation, but are a formatting placeholder used as part of `String.Format`.  A string with a placeholder wont use automatically know what to do with it. Your `MySQLCommand` object certainly doesn't know how to use it, so you get the error.  Eg:

```
connector.Open()
Dim SQL As String = String.Format("UPDATE pupil_data SET '{0}'='{1}' WHERE 'username'='{2}'", 
       Question, Answer, Environment.Username)
commander = New MySqlCommand(SQL, connector)
dataAdapter = New MySqlDataAdapter(commander)
connector.Close()
```

I am not sure you need all those ticks in the SQL either.  Note that if something like `Question` is a numeric, you need to convert to string:

```
Dim SQL As String = String.Format("Update ...", 
       Question.ToString, Answer.ToString, Environment.Username)
```

There are a few things like `Console.WriteLine`, `StringBuilder.AppendFormat` which automatically implement this as well.

See [String.Format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format(v=vs.110).aspx)

**Note that this is absolutely the wrong way to create SQL.**  If user name for instance is `D'Artagnan` the query will choke.  String.Format does not protect you from SQL Injection, its just neater code than concatenating bits of string together.